# Cauchy problem I can't solve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following Cauchy problem:
\begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
   y'=y^4\\y(0)=0
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
I thought that Peano-Picard's theorem hypothesis were verified: $y^4$ is locally lipschitz in a neighbourhood of zero and it is continuos. So I can't understand why I can't use the Picard approximation method. Plus, according to Wolfram Alpha, I have multiple solutions. I am a "newbie" on this theory, so maybe I'm missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you *can* use [Picard's approximation method](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/picard/picard.html) (or, if you prefer [a more $\LaTeX$-ed source...](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~seal/teaching/f09/picard_iteration.pdf)).

If you set up the iteration $$\begin{cases}y_0(x)\equiv y(0)=0\\ y_{n+1}(x)=y(0)+\int_0^x(y_{n}(t))^4\,dt\end{cases}$$

You get $y_n(x)\equiv 0$ for all $n$. Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$ gives you exactly the solution.

I don't know what Wolframalpha said, but your problem satisfies the hypothesis of [Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cauchy-Lipschitz_theorem), hence the solution exists and it is unique.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got confused because trying with the separation if variables I got the same result of Kim Peek in the comment below, so I started thinking there was something wrong. Maybe the problem is that when I divide by $y^4(x)$ I "throw away" the solution $y^4(x)=0$, which is my only solution. Am I right? Anyway thank you very much G. Sassatelli, now everything is more clear :)

Comment: Yes, you are. You must always check the case where the initial condition annihilates the denomiantor before separating the variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a hint**

$$y'(x) = y^4(x)$$

$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} = y^4(x)$$

$$\frac{\text{d}y}{y^4} = \text{d}x$$

Integrating:

$$-\frac{1}{3y^3} = x + C$$

namely

$$y(x) = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{3x + C}}$$

Can you continue by yourself?

Comment: This is a good hint, but it ignores the real question of how to fit the initial condition, and how to deal with the solution $y(x)\equiv 0$.

Comment: $y(0) = 0$ only means that in the solution you set $x = 0$ to find what $C$ should be in order to get $0$.

Comment: Of course, but what about the alternative solution to the problem, $y(x)=0$ for all values of $x$? It is this seeming multiplicity of solutions that has the OP confused. In addition, no value of $C$ in the solution you propose satisfies the initial condition.

Comment: That's true. I will think more about!

Comment: This is a common issue when solving ODEs by the method of separation; you have to make sure you consider what happens when you divide by zero.

Comment: Replace $C=1/D$ to get $$y(x) = -\sqrt[3]{\frac{D}{1+3Dx}}.$$ Then the zero solution is included in this family for $D=0$. Actually, use $C=-1/(y(0)^3)$ to get $$y(x) = y(0)·\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{1-3y(0)^3·x}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

There is only one solution that is zero at zero: zero.

If it is non-zero at zero then you get the other solutions.

I really don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'(x)=y(x)^4\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^4}=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^4}\space\text{d}x=\int1\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\frac{1}{3y(x)^3}=x+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{y(x)^3}=-3\left(x+\text{C}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)^3=-\frac{1}{3\left(x+\text{C}\right)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)^3=\left|-\frac{1}{3\left(x+\text{C}\right)}\right|e^{\arg\left(-\frac{1}{3\left(x+\text{C}\right)}\right)i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=\left[\left|-\frac{1}{3\left(x+\text{C}\right)}\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(-\frac{1}{3\left(x+\text{C}\right)}\right)+2\pi k\right)i}\right]^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

With $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k:0-2$

Comment: How do you recover the solution $y(x)\equiv 0$ - the one with $y(0)=0$ - from your calculations?